# Creating a list of list after traversing binary search tree in level order

Tags: java, tree, interview-questions

Here is my code.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
 public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
        if (root == null) {
            return list;
        } else {
            Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<>();
            q.add(root);
            while (!q.isEmpty()) {
                int size = q.size();
                LinkedList<Integer> layers = new LinkedList<>();
                while (size != 0) {
                    TreeNode current = q.poll();
                    layers.add(current.val);
                    if (current.left != null) {
                        q.add(current.left);
                    }
                    if (current.right != null) {
                        q.add(current.right);
                    }
                    size--;
                }

                list.add(layers);

            }
        }
        return list;

    }

}
```

Please let me know if any improvement/correction.

Comment: Some vertical space (new lines)  to group related code would increase readability.

Answer (score 4):

Nicely done. I especially like how you used the size of the queue to know how many items are there on the level. I have only minor improvement ideas.

---

You can simplify this declaration:

> ```
> List<List<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
> ```

Using the diamond operator `<>`, like you already did at other places:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

---

The code is deeply indented. You could reduce the indent level by eliminating the `else` branch of the outermost condition:

```
    if (root == null) {
        return list;
    }
    Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(root);
    // ...
```

---

The `while` loop could be written as a `for` loop. The benefit is that it will be harder to forget to decrement `size`.

---

Lastly, some of the names could be better.

- Instead of "layers", I propose singular "layer"
- Instead of "size", I propose "count"

Answer (score 1):

Nice iterative way of solving it. 
I can also think of a simple recursive way of doing this. In this approach, you simply keep on adding values to the listOfLists based on the level index. Here is the code:

```
private static List<List<Integer>> getLists(TreeNode root){
    List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new LinkedList<>();
    if(root == null)
        return listOfLists;
    getListsRec(root,listOfLists,1);
    return listOfLists;
}

private static void getListsRec(TreeNode root, List<List<Integer>> listOfLists, int level) {
    if(root == null)
        return ;
    if(listOfLists.size() < level ){
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(root.value);
        listOfLists.add(list);
    }
    else{
        List<Integer> list = listOfLists.get(level -1);
        list.add(root.value);
    }
    getListsRec(root.left, listOfLists, level+1);
    getListsRec(root.right, listOfLists, level+1);
}
```

Edit: This can be improved little bit:-

```
    private static List<List<Integer>> getLists(TreeNode root){
    List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new LinkedList<>();
    if(root == null)
        return listOfLists;
    getListsRec(root,listOfLists,1);
    return listOfLists;
}

private static void getListsRec(TreeNode root, List<List<Integer>> listOfLists, int level) {
    if(root == null)
        return ;

    if(listOfLists.size() < level ){
        listOfLists.add(new LinkedList<>());
    }

    listOfLists.get(level -1).add(root.value);

    getListsRec(root.left, listOfLists, level+1);
    getListsRec(root.right, listOfLists, level+1);
}
```